# Property 'uri' does not exist on type 'WebViewSource' in React Native Webview component

Tags: typescript, react-native, webview

I have the following TypeScript error:

```
Property 'uri' does not exist on type 'WebViewSource'.
  Property 'uri' does not exist on type 'WebViewSourceHtml'.ts(2339)
```

For the code:

```
import {WebView, WebViewProps} from 'react-native-webview';

return(
   <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => openLinkInNativeBrowser(route?.params?.source?.uri)}
          >
            <VectorImage
              source={SafariIcon}
              style={styles.webViewSafariIconVector}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
);
```

It looks like I need to get types from Webview but I am not sure where they are.